# "Skipping" some lines/columns on ArrayFormulas?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a table with a list of interesting places in cities. The columns would be "place", "city" and "state" (just an example). In another sheet, I want to make a summary of my data as "number of places" by city and by state. I want that to be automatically calculated from the data entry sheet.

Sample data entry sheet:

```
Place   | City     | State
--------|----------|------
Park    | Rio      | RJ
Pool    | Rio      | RJ
Bath    | Sampa    | SP
Blabla  | Sampa    | SP
Another | Mesquita | RJ
```

I can make summaries by city OR state easily with some unique/filter/counta etc, but I can't really "organize" it in a way I have both information (by city and by state) at the same time using a formula. It's simple to get up to...

```
State | City     | N
------|----------|---
RJ    | Rio      | 2
RJ    | Mesquita | 1
SP    | Sampa    | 2
```

But my ideal result would be something like:

```
State | City     | N
------|----------|---
RJ    | ----     | 3
      | Rio      | 2
      | Mesquita | 1
SP    | ----     | 2
      | Sampa    | 2
```

The doubt is about the "State" and "City" columns. I once did something close to it using intermediate summary data, arrayformulas, `repeat`, `split` and `transpose`, but never went this far.

Any lights?

Comment: Use pivot tables it would be easy to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=QUERY({A1:C6;{QUERY(A2:C6,"select A,'------',C",0)}},"Select Col3,Col2,count(Col1) where Not Col2 contains '()' group by Col3,Col2",1)
```

We double up the given array - One `as-is` and an another, the middle column substituted with `-----`. From there, We run a `QUERY` on the doubled up array to give the requested result.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)